# Selected value of RadioButton not getting when using the model class object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a radiobutton, textbox, dropdown in my MVC application registration page, to save the values selected in the I used as follows.(i.e for checking purpose I used both the Formcollection and also the Employee_Info class object. but when debugging when I used formcollection I get the selected value, but when Employee_Info Object `empObjc` I am getting it was `null`. Why is that so . What I can I do.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("EditEmployeeDetails")]
    public ActionResult EditEmployeeDetails_Post(int personid, 
                        Employee_Info empObjc, FormCollection a)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TryUpdateModel(empObjc);            
            int ModifiedBy = Convert.ToInt16(Session["LoginPersonID"]);
            empBsnObj.UpdateUserDetailss(personid, empObjc, ModifiedBy);
            //empContextObj.Entry(empObjc).State = EntityState.Modified;
            return RedirectToAction("DisplayEmployeeList", "Admin");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

My View is

```
@model EmployeeManagementDAL.Employee_Info

<h2>Edit Details</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) <br/>
{ <br/>
<table><tr><td>Is Indian?  <br/> <br/>
</td><td>Yes  @Html.RadioButtonFor(x=>x.IsIndian, "Yes")
       <br/>   <br/> No   @Html.RadioButtonFor(x=>x.IsIndian, "No") <br/>}
```

I modified as follows

```
  public ActionResult EditEmployeeDetails_Post(int id) <br/>
    { <br/>
        if (ModelState.IsValid) <br/>
        { <br/>
            Employee_Info empObjc = new Employee_Info(); <br/>
            TryUpdateModel(empObjc);        <br/>        
            int ModifiedBy = Convert.ToInt16(Session["LoginPersonID"]); <br/>
            empBsnObj.UpdateUserDetailss(id, empObjc, ModifiedBy); <br/>

            return RedirectToAction("DisplayEmployeeList", "Admin"); <br/>
        } <br/>
        return View(); <br/>
    }
```

Comment: Does your view is tightly coupled with `@model Employee_Info`? Add your view code also

Comment: set the controller and action attribute to the form correctly. It is missing in `BeginForm`

Comment: @Murali I got an error saying the id parameter is null. so I modified my method and posted above description and then used my previous view itself without binding that controller and actionname in the beginform(). but still I am getting it as null when debugging

Comment: @tereško Didnot understand your response

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have the `model specified for the view.`

If you miss please add like below

```
@model Employee_Info

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditEmployeeDetails", "Employee"))
{
   <div>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.FirstName)
   </div>
}
```